# Numpy.array creates column major matrix from an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, column-major-order

I am trying to open an image which has 960 (width) x 640 (height) pixels as a matrix in python.

For some reason, after running the following lines:

```
originalImage = Image.open('fat_zack.jpg')
originalImageMatrix = numpy.asarray(originalImage)
```

`originalImageMatrix` is of size `(640, 960, 3)` and I have to access its elements by providing column coordinate prior to row coordinate

If I try to do something like: `originalImageMatrix[959][1][1]` I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 959 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 640
```

Do you've any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Well as you said, the first coordinate has at most 640 rows. The second one has up to 960.

Comment: the thing is the image has 640 columns, not rows, the height is set as first dimension instead of the width

Comment: You can use Numpy [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to interchange the 0th and 1st axes.

Comment: The height of the image is 640. In array form that means 640 rows. You pick a bottom pixel with `arr[639,0,:]`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with Matt Pitkin's solution -> originalImageMatrix.swapaxes(0, 1)

What causes this problem is still unknown to me, though.